# want to locate a photo element with selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

https://mammothworkwear.com/safety-boots/
I want to locate a product item in that link and click it.

The page object looks like:

```
elements: {
        menuItem: 'nav[role="navigation"] ul li a',
        productItem: 'main .pitem a'
    },

clickProductItem: function(containingText) {

        return helpers.clickHiddenElement(page.mammothWorkwear.elements.productItem, containingText);
        
    },
```

With these code, the product item cannot be located. Any idea? thanks.

Comment: The CSS that you've `main .pitem a` here, represent `<a href="https://mammothworkwear.com/himalayan-waterproof-s3-steel-poron-met-guard-boots-p11620.htm"><img src="https://mammothworkwear.com/himalayan-waterproof-s3-steel-poron-metatarsal-guard-boots-w160h160q94i35118.jpg" width="160" height="160" alt="Himalayan Waterproof S3 Steel Poron Metatarsal Guard Boots - 5208"><h2>Himalayan Waterproof S3 Steel Poron Metatarsal Guard Boots</h2></a>` in HTML DOm, what is your intention to locate?

Comment: I intent to find an element which contain the text "Timberland PRO Disruptor Safety Chukka Boot".